# How to close a mission control space using hotkey?

Tags: macos, applescript, bash, bettertouchtool

Using "Better Touch tool", I have a hotkey set to "Add New Space To Mission Control". I would like to create the inverse of this and set a hotkey to close the current space. Specifically, I would like hotkeys to open and close desktop workspaces.

If this isn't build into BTT, is there a bash command which can be used to accomplish this?

Comment: What version of macOS and BBT are you using?

Comment: I was originally on 2.405, though I enabled automatic updates and I'm currently on 2.444. I'm using MacOS High Sierra 10.13.3